# ng2-charts\ng2-charts.js does not export ChartsModule

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am trying to use the basic example of NG2-Charts (http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/)

I copy pasted the HTML part

```
<div style="display: block">
<canvas baseChart
        [datasets]="barChartData"
        [labels]="barChartLabels"
        [options]="barChartOptions"
        [legend]="barChartLegend"
        [chartType]="barChartType"
        (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
        (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
```

and the TypeScript part

```
public barChartOptions:any = {
scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
responsive: true
};
public barChartLabels:string[] = 
['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010','2011', '2012'];

public barChartType:string = 'bar';
public barChartLegend:boolean = true;

public barChartData:any[] = [
{data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A'},
{data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B'}
];

// events
public chartClicked(e:any):void {
console.log(e);
}

public chartHovered(e:any):void {
console.log(e);
}

public randomize():void {
// Only Change 3 values
let data = [
Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
  59,
  80,
(Math.random() * 100),
 56,
 (Math.random() * 100),
 40];
let clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.barChartData));
clone[0].data = data;
this.barChartData = clone;
/**
 * (My guess), for Angular to recognize the change in the dataset
 * it has to change the dataset variable directly,
 * so one way around it, is to clone the data, change it and then
 * assign it;
 */
 }
```

I run npm install ng2-charts --save, npm install chart.js --save

I also import ChartsModule in app.module.ts

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';
@NgModule({
  imports: [ChartsModule]
})
```

[After importing ChartsModule I am getting an error that ***ng2-charts\ng2-charts.js does not export ChartsModule.*** 
Click to view the image of an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHw1G.png)

Does anyone has an idea on how to fix that?
Thank you

Comment: Please take a look on the following answer on issue [**#440**](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/440#issuecomment-251671800) at their github.

Comment: Still it is not working.
It is also showing an error that "Can't bind to 'datasets' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'"

Comment: Did you create the project using angular-cli? If so, in the angular-cli.json file, in the "scripts" section, try adding this:         "../node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js"

Answer (score 3):

The second issue in the comments

> It is also showing an error that "Can't bind to 'datasets' since it
> isn't a known property of 'canvas'

is probably due to not importing ChartsModule into the module that is rendering the chart.

I had encountered the same initial issue and was able to get past it by adding the following to my rollup-config file

```
plugins: [
    nodeResolve({jsnext: true, module: true}),
    commonjs({
        include: ['node_modules/rxjs/**','node_modules/ng2-charts/**'],
        namedExports: {'node_modules/ng2-charts/ng2-charts.js': ['ChartsModule']} 
    }),
    uglify()
]
```

The documentation for this library could have been better.

I hope the post can help anyone encountering similar issues

Comment: the link is broken