# ng2-charts - Can't bind to 'datasets' since it isn't a known property of 'base-chart'

Tags: angular, ionic2, ng2-charts

*Versions: Cordova: 6.3.1, Gulp CLI: 1.2.2, Ionic framework: 2.0.0-rc.0, Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0*

---

I'm using [ng2-charts](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts) in my ionic2 application.

Import not `import {ChartsModule} from "ng2-charts";`
but `import {ChartsModule} from "ng2-charts/components/charts/charts;"` because of [this (issue #440)](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/440#issuecomment-251671800)

My entire **app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/components/charts/charts';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { EventsPage } from '../pages/events/events.component';
import { ChartComponent } from '../pages/chart/chart.component';
import { APICaller } from '../services/APICaller.service';
import { EventDetailComponent } from '../pages/event-detail/event-detail.component';
import { ParticipantDetail } from '../pages/participant-detail/participant-detail.component';
import { ParticipantFeedComponent } from '../pages/participant-feed/participant-feed.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    EventsPage,
    EventDetailComponent,
    ParticipantDetail,
    ParticipantFeedComponent,
    ChartComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    ChartsModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    EventsPage,
    EventDetailComponent,
    ParticipantDetail,
    ParticipantFeedComponent,
    ChartComponent
  ],
  providers: [APICaller]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**ChartComponent**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'pie-chart',
    template: `

<base-chart
    class="chart"
    [datasets]="datasets"
    [labels]="labels"
    [options]="options"
    [chartType]="'doughnut'">Titel?
</base-chart>

`
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {
    private datasets = [
        {
            label: "# of Votes",
            data: [12,19,3,5,2,3]
        }
    ];


    private labels = ['Red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'purple', 'orange'];

    private options = {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                beginAtZero: true
            }]
        }
    };

    constructor() {

    }

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

I thought this might be an issue with `Chart.js`. And I found that the `chart.js` installed with npm was resulting in a 404 when referencing it in my `index.html` as `node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js`.

So I downloaded the `Chart.bundle.min.js` after this didn't work I tried downloading the `Chart.js` itself. (placing it in `src/assets/js/...`).

This problem was also addressed in [ng2-charts\ng2-charts.js does not export ChartsModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032174/ng2-charts-ng2-charts-js-does-not-export-chartsmodule)  's comment section. But since no answer has been provided and this wasn't the root question, I posted this one.

**Error:** (suppressing the errormessage won't help since it's stopping my app from loading).

```
polyfills.js:3 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'datasets' since it isn't a known property of 'base-chart'.
1. If 'base-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'datasets' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'base-chart' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("
    class="chart"

    [ERROR ->][datasets]="datasets"

    [labels]="labels"
"): ChartComponent@4:4
Can't bind to 'labels' since it isn't a known property of 'base-chart'.
1. If 'base-chart' is an Angular component and it has 'labels' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'base-chart' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("
    [datasets]="datasets"

    [ERROR ->][labels]="labels"

    [options]="options"
"): ChartComponent@6:4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used this library, but from just looking at [the latest (1.4.1) version's source code](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/blob/v1.4.1/components/charts/charts.ts#L18), it should be used as an attribute on a canvas `@Directive({selector: 'canvas[baseChart]'})`

```
<canvas baseChart
   class="chart"
   [data]="datasets"
   [labels]="labels"
   [options]="options"
   [chartType]="'doughnut'">
</canvas>
```

Comment: it's now not throwing the error anymore but the chart isn't displayed

Comment: Maybe you need to add a size to it, I don't know. Do you have width/height for the css class?

Comment: fixed it using this plunker. Ill accept your answer since it did answer the question. https://plnkr.co/edit/MWE0umGfN3nZM6zLPPVI?p=preview

Comment: turns out changing the `[datasets]` to `[data]` was the difference, wished they documented `ng2-charts` better...

Comment: Yeah briefly going through the docs, it looks like it needs to be updated

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but your solution does not work for me.  Has anyone else seen another solution to this issue?

Comment: Hello! I am facing the same error too... How did you all solve it? Thank you.